# Regex for matching a string that can end with a character or not

Tags: regex, .htaccess, pattern-matching

I have this regex

```
^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/$
```

It matches a generic url, like

```
www.site.com/complete/path/for/this/page/
```

The problem is that if i go to

```
www.site.com/complete/path/for/this/page
```

I get a 404 error, because my regex matches that string only if it ends with a slash.

How can i tell the regex to match the string whether it ends with a slash or not?

I thought about duplicating my rules to match the two cases but i think it is a very ugly way to do it, i'm sure that there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Make the slash optional

```
^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/?$
```

by putting a `?` after it.

`?` is a [quantifier that repeats the preceding element 0 or 1 time](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), so it makes it optional.

Comment: It doesn't work, it redirects me to the errer 404 page even if i add `?` after the slash

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/([^>]+)/?$
```

So its 5 expected slashes and 1 optional one in the end? Try this.

Comment: There are 4 expected slashes and the fifth that could exist or not. However, same answer as **stema**'s, already said it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, I've put an extra slash and a non-> character in the pattern compared to stema's answer.

Comment: Yes, and it's wrong, because i need it to match `a/b/c/d/e/` or `a/b/c/d/e` as written in the question, not `a/b/c/d/e/f` so i have 4 expected slashes instead of 5